# Good Active Flexibility Stretch for Mid Back

Tags: exercise, stretching, flexibility, yoga, gymnastics

What is a good "Active Flexibility" Stretch for Mid back?

Note: Active Flexibility is different from Passive/Static.
Resource: [Passive vs Active Flexibility Stretch](https://camillamia.com/active-vs-passive-flexibility)

"Active flexibility is the range of motion a joint can move into without an external force helping it go there. (In my mind,  it does not use the wall, or gravity pushing against ground, eg splits).
Passive flexibility is the range of motion a joint can move into when there's an external force helping it go there."

**Good active flexibility stretch for Lower Back:**

[image]

**Good active flexibility stretch for Upper Back/Shoulders:**

[image]
[image]

**I am trying to find a good active flexibility stretch for mid back:**

Here is the "Passive Flexibility" stretch for mid back (which leverages the wall). Trying to find a good corresponding "Active flexibility stretch".

[image]

Credits to "[Aerial Practice](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCajoXdHG0Vh1298uKbYl-ZA)" on Youtube.

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer is barbell front squats, I've never had an exercise work my mid-back extension like those do.

Comment: hi @DarkHippo yeah , I do squats also

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the following:

- [bow pose, dhanurasana](https://www.yogajournal.com/poses/bow-pose/) or
- [locust pose, salabhasana](https://www.yogajournal.com/poses/locust-pose/) or
- [snake pose, sarpasana](https://yogaindiafoundation.com/sarpasana-snake-pose/)

I find all of them work on my mid-back (not necessarily exclusively or in isolation). They also provide a lot of room for progression; you can start where you are and slowly come to mastery and find that the back, including midback muscles become very strong in the process.